# Cosine similarity of Documents

Tags: r, text-mining, cosine-similarity

Data format CSV

Total number of documents 500. number of fields 10.

view of data [image]

i want to calculate parallel cosine similarity  of Each "Docs" with all 500 documents,

expected out put

[image]

Comment: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) with your questions. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks. For statistics questions, use stats.stackexchange.com.**

Comment: Also google: `"cosine similarity r"`. Hope this helps.

Comment: `help("stringdist::stringdist")`.

Comment: Looking at your "data" and your "expected ouput", they appear to be the same but only with a new column that says "consine similarity". I suppose you want a number here, right? If so, could you elaborate on exatly what you want to compute? The cosine similarity is takes two vectors **of the same length**. So in the first row, I suppose you want the simillarity of doc "u10072963", but with what other document exactly? If you want all combinations of documents, your expected output should look a bit different (either as a similarity matrix or new column added).

Comment: yes i want a number where there is cosine similarity . 
i want to calculate the similarity of doc "u10072963"  with all other 500 docs and as so on .
it's oky if the expected output id different sir .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want? To compute the similarity of all (500*499)/2 combinations, you can do something like this:

```
# Create some mock data
df <-replicate(10, rnorm(500))
rownames(df) <- paste0("doc", seq_len(nrow(df)))
colnames(df) <- paste0("field", seq_len(ncol(df)))


# Vector lengths
vl <- sqrt(rowSums(df*df))

# Matrix of all combinations
comb <- t(combn(1:nrow(df), 2))

# Compute cosine similarity for all combinations
csim <- apply(comb, 1, FUN = function(i) sum(apply(df[i, ], 2, prod))/prod(vl[i]))

# Create a data.frame of the results
res <- data.frame(docA = rownames(df)[comb[,1]],
                  docB = rownames(df)[comb[,2]],
                  csim = csim)
head(res)
#  docA docB       csim
#1 doc1 doc2 -0.6431972
#2 doc1 doc3 -0.2560444
#3 doc1 doc4 -0.4911942
#4 doc1 doc5 -0.2207487
#5 doc1 doc6  0.4764924
#6 doc1 doc7  0.5867607

tail(res)
#         docA   docB      csim
#124745 doc497 doc498 1.0714338
#124746 doc497 doc499 0.8439304
#124747 doc497 doc500 1.1806366
#124748 doc498 doc499 0.9326781
#124749 doc498 doc500 1.4783254
#124750 doc499 doc500 1.3626494
```

Note, it does not really make sense to have the original vector values of the fields in this output table. Each number is a comparison and coputation of two rows in your data.

**Edit**:

If you want it no matrix form, you can compute it directly by:

```
res_mat <- tcrossprod(df)/tcrossprod(vl)
print(res_mat[1:5, 1:5])
#           doc1       doc2       doc3       doc4       doc5
#doc1  1.0000000 -0.6431972 -0.2560444 -0.4911942 -0.2207487
#doc2 -0.6431972  1.0000000  0.3996618  0.3365490 -0.1434239
#doc3 -0.2560444  0.3996618  1.0000000  0.2856842  0.2781019
#doc4 -0.4911942  0.3365490  0.2856842  1.0000000  0.2287057
#doc5 -0.2207487 -0.1434239  0.2781019  0.2287057  1.0000000
```

Comment: this is what i want . kindly teel me how can i get the output result like 
(      d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
d1 o 
d2 1 2 
d3 1 2 3 
d4 1 2 3 4
d5 1 2 3 4 5 )
kindly copy past the values in brackets to notepad to better understand what i mean